# Display whitespaces from database

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm making comment section for my page, and I'm trying to make them work properly.
The problem is that when I save comment to DB, for example like this:

```
My comment
  {
     ohh
  }
```

and when displaying it like `echo $comment`, I get:

```
My comment { ohh }
```

So I fixed this with:

```
nl2br(preg_replace('/(\r)|(\n)/', '<br>', $comment->text));
```

Now I get:

```
My comment
{
ohh
}
```

But I need to display the first variant. When I vardie it gives me:

```
string(36) "My comment
{
ohh
}"
```

In db it's storing comment with all indents.

So question: How do I correctly display comment with whitespaces. And also extra question, how I store these comments to DB to allow only 4 sequent whitespaces??, it doesn't matter on the beginning or in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

One solution (possibly not ideal) would be to wrap the text in `<pre></pre>`, e.g.:

```
<pre><?php echo $comment; ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (also possibly not ideal) would be to replace spaces with an HTML non-breaking space. You can wrap it around your "newlines to `<br>`" function:

```
str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', preg_replace('/(\r)|(\n)/', '<br>', $comment->text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert whitespaces to `&nbsp;` before inserting into the database.

```
$_POST['code_field'] = str_ireplace(' ' , '&nbsp;' , $_POST['code_field']);
```

If you are allowing for editing of comments then convert `&nbsp;` back into regular spaces.

```
$row['code_field'] = str_ireplace('&nbsp;' , ' ' , $row['code_field']);
```